# How to eager load children in Parse query?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a many-to-many relationship of Team and Person. A team never has more than a few people. I am trying to eager load the Teams with their people. I am doing this using the `include` method:

```
ParseQuery.getQuery(Team.class)
    .orderByAscending("Name")
    .include("Team.People")
    .findInBackground(FindCallback);
```

But how do I then access the persons on the team?

`team.getList("People")` always returns null, since People is a relation, not a List.

`team.get("People")` returns the `Relation`, but relation only has methods to add and remove people. No way to see existing people without issuing another query.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of the members of the team, you should call

```
ArrayList<ParseObject> teamMembers = team.getList("People");
```

Comment: Unfortunately that always returns null. Inspecting the team object in the debugger shows that "People" is a ParseRelation, not a List. I will update question

Comment: Then, are you sure that People is the name of the attribute in your Parse table and not the name of the ParseTable ? you can also remove the Team.People (replace with 'People'), dot is used for multi-level eagger loading.

Comment: In the parse admin the column shows as "People Relation<Person>" which is correct I would think....? Each row has a button "View Relations" which does correctly show the related people.

Comment: Yes it is. Have you tryed include("People") instead of ("Team.People") ?

Comment: When I try that it throws an exception "People cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object". I think that's more for a many-to-one and not many-to-many.

Comment: I'm starting to think it just isn't possible to do what I want. I need to model it as a List instead of a Relation, and then it all just works without even using the include. Seems like it's not the "right" way to do it though. Upvote for your help